# Submitting update to existing app on Google Play Store: "An error occurred while running bundletool build-apks"

Tags: android, google-play, android-app-bundle

I am submitting an update to an Android app that has existed in the Google Play Store for some time. It uses Android App Bundles (and also, has for some time).

With this recent attempt to upload, AFTER the upload is complete, I get the following error message: "An error occurred while running bundletool build-apks on your uploaded app bundle. Ensure that your app bundle is valid by running bundletool build-apks locally and try again. Learn More"

Following the "Learn More" link, I find that I can run bundletool locally to see what the issues are. So I downloaded bundletool, ran it, and.... nothing. It was successful. (I ran it using the same key store, alias, etc. that I used to build the aab.)

As mentioned, this isn't the first time submitting as an App Bundle, so my manifest(s) are -- I assume -- configured correctly (tools:replace="android:hasCode") and so on.

Comment: Reach out to [Play Developer support](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7218994?hl=en), that's the best way to get a Google engineer to investigate the issue.

Comment: @Pierre Thank you. I've done that but so far aside from a request for more info (which I provided) I haven't heard anything in 2 days despite following up so I thought I'd also post here since the client is getting very antsy.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into an issue which generated the same error message:

> An error occurred while running bundletool build-apks on your uploaded App Bundle. Ensure that your App Bundle is valid by running bundletool build-apks locally

In my release dashboard, I noticed that a previous attempt had been aborted and that there was a draft version of said attempt.

Once i discarded the draft, I was able to properly upload my `aab`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the latest version of bundletool is not stellar at reporting on errors (or rather, just blatantly succeeding when it shouldn't) and it is a different version than the one currently running behind the scenes in the Google Play Console.

My issue was, the minSdkVersion in my dynamic feature differed from that of my main project. And although this succeeded in the local version of bundletool, it failed when trying to upload to Google Play. Once I synched up those minSdkVersion's, everything went back to working as it had in the past.

Comment: Just to clarify, the actual issue is that another validation (on the minSdkVersion) was added to bundletool but that version wasn't released publicly yet.

Answer (score 0):

For me restarting windows, and creating the app bundle again worked.